# Sitemap creation with Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

Is it possible to use Scrapy to generate a sitemap of a website including the URL of each page and its level/depth (the number of links I need to follow from the home page to get there)? The format of the sitemap doesn't have to be XML, it's just about the information. Furthermore I'd like to save the complete HTML source of the crawled pages for further analysis instead of scraping only certain elements from it.

Could somebody experienced in using Scrapy tell me whether this is a possible/reasonable scenario for Scrapy and give me some hints on how to find instructions? So far I could only find far more complex scenarios but no approach for this seemingly simple problem.

Addon for experienced webcrawlers: Given it is possible, do you think Scrapy is even the right tool for this? Or would it be easier to write my own crawler with a library like requests etc.?

Comment: I'm not sure crawling a site to generate a sitemap is necessarily the right approach. Is this a website you developed or administered? If so, what was it built with?

Comment: No, it is not mine, and unfortunately I can also not expect the website to already have a sitemap I could use. I want to use this crawler to analyze websites and for that I need their sitemap and content.

Comment: Well, there are existing specialised tools for generating sitemaps and if your only goal is to generate a sitemap I'd use one of them rather than rolling my own.

Comment: Could you provide me with some links or names? I can only find tools to use on your own websites.

Comment: [This one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sitemap-generator) was on the first page of the search results and seems OK.

Answer (score -1):

- Yes, it's possible to do what you're trying with Scrapy's LinkExtractor library. This will help you document the URLs for all of the pages on your site.
- Once this is done, you can iterate through the URLs and the source (HTML) for each page using the urllib Python library.
- Then you can use RegEx to find whatever patterns you're looking for within the HTML for each page in order to perform your analysis.